# Ensure directory tree exists from variable

Tags: windows, puppet

In puppet I am trying to install a package on a windows machine. The package can take the `INSTALLDIR` parameter, which determines where it installs. I want to ensure that the directory that the package is installing to exists. However, unless I am mistaken, puppet is not the nicest for managing whole directory trees. The suggested methods online seem to be either managing each folder in the tree separately like so:

```
file{
    ['parent','parent/firstchild', 'parent/firstchild/lastchild]:
    ensure => directory, 
}
```

or having the directory structure already present in the modules file folder, or running an exec that creates the directory tree (which I would like to avoid as it is not exactly ensuring a state, which is the goal of puppet).

**How would I check if a directory is present and if not create it in puppet *from* a variable?**

Relevant code:

```
$installDir = "C:/folder1/folder2/folder3"

package{ "MagicalPackage":
        ensure  => $installValue,
        source  => 'magic.msi',
        install_options => ["INSTALLDIR=${installDir}"],

}
```

Comment: Puppet won't check if the directory exists then create it. you would need to explicitly manage the directory to ensure it is present. You can't even write a custom function really because functions run on the master not the agent.

Comment: I want to be able to explicitly manage a directory tree based on a variable.

Comment: The only way I see that happening is if you write a custom function to split the directory path. then you can do `$installDir = custom_function('C:/folder1/folder2/folder3')` which could possibly equate to `$installDir = ['C:/folder1','C:/folder1/folder2','C:/folder1/folder2/folder3'` which you can then pass to the file resource `file { $installDir: ensure => directory }`. I don't see this happening another way.

Comment: Ah, well that sucks. Feels very ugly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path.  I think that this should work.

```
# Create install directory
file{ ["C:\folder1\", "C:\folder1\folder2", "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3" ]:
    ensure => "directory", 
}

# Set install directory
$installDir = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3"

# Software
package { "MagicalPackage":
    ensure  => "installed",
    source  => 'magic.msi',
    require => $installDir,
    install_options => [ "INSTALLDIR = ${installDir}" ],
}

# Config file
file { "MagicalConfig":
    path    => "C:\Config\Path",
    ensure  => "file",
    require => Package[ 'MagicalPackage' ],
}

# Service is on
service { 
    enabled => true,
}
```

Comment: What you stated in the `file` resource is what the OP was trying to avoid. OP was asking for a programmatic solution to creating the full directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [feature](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/86) that has long been asked for, but it wasn't possible to find a satisfactory design.

If you don't wish to manage each directory on the path explicitly, then I can see two options here:

1. You just pass the `INSTALLDIR` and look out for error messages from the `package` resource
2. You add [custom facts](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.1/custom_facts.html) for each such `INSTALLDIR` you want to use - you can then query the state from the manifest